# Difference between the smallest and biggest number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck with the following assignment.

*Code this function to take an array and return the difference between the smallest and the biggest number.*

I've tried the following but keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function differenceMinMax(array) {

     var arrayMin = array[0];
     var arrayMax = array [0];

     for  (var i=0; i <= array.length; i++) {

     if (array[i] < arrayMin) {
       arrayMin = array[i];
     } 
     if (array[i] > arrayMax) {
       arrayMax = array[i];
     }
    }

    return arrayMax - arrayMin;

    }
```

Comment: `lenght` Spelling often matters in programming

Comment: You can only test a condition in an `if` and not in an `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. array[array.length] is not exist so change

   `i <= array.lenght`

   to

   `i < array.length`
2. change

   `else (array[i] > arrayMax)`

   to

   `else if(array[i] > arrayMax)`

Comment: Thanks! I've changed lenght to length but I'm still getting an error. Do you see any other flaw in my code?

Comment: i added number 2

Answer (score 0):

For your example to work, you could change your `else` to `else if` in your if/else clause. Also, change `i <= array.length` to `i < array.length`. Array's length is always numerically greater than its highest index (by 1), because in javascript indexes start from 0.

Here's how to do it with way less code, using ES6.

```js
const diff = (arr) => Math.max(...arr) - Math.min(...arr);

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [99, 0, -99];

console.log(diff(arr1)); // Logs 4
console.log(diff(arr2)); // Logs 198
```

Comment: This might work but throwing some ES6 "magic" at a beginner won't help them to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your array and try this below code, It will work.

```js
var array = ['56', '1','9','0','20','2021'];
var max = min= 0;

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if(parseInt(array[i]) > parseInt(max))
    {
    
      max = array[i]
      if(i == 0)
      min = max
    }
    else if(parseInt(array[i]) < parseInt(min))
    {
//console.log(max_2)    
      min = array[i];
    }
}
console.log("Maximum Number In Your Array "+ max)
console.log("Manimum Number In Your Array "+min)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//We are going to sort the array, find the first & last elem of the array and perform the operation
var array = [9, 12, 14, 3, 5, 67];

var difference = differenceBetweenLargestAndSmallestElement(array);

console.log(difference);

function differenceBetweenLargestAndSmallestElement(array) {
  var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });

  console.log(sortedArray);

  var firstElement = sortedArray[0];
  var lastElement = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1];

  return lastElement - firstElement;
}
```

> Please find a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Ayyub/zysp63fm/12/

Answer (score -1):

try this : 'var arrayMin = 0; var arrayMax = 0;' instead of 'var arrayMin = array[0];var arrayMax = array [0]'